# BUG: How to prevent the enemy's health bar to reset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently working on a RPG like game using python and tkinter.
The problem is that after pressing on the Heal button and then pressing any attack button, the enemy's health bar will reset.

I already tried to understand from where the error is coming but it didn't bare fruit. I used print() after every line to verify the values but none of this answered my question.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import font
import time 
import threading
import random

class InGameWindow(object) :
    def __init__(self, master) :
        #Window and it's settings
        self.master = master

        windowWidth = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        windowHeight = self.master.winfo_screenheight()

        rootCoord = f"800x400+{int((windowWidth/2)-400)}+{int((windowHeight/2)-200)}"

        master.title("A Simple RPG")
        master.geometry(rootCoord)
        master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        master.overrideredirect(False)
        master.configure(bg="black")

        #Import files as .png etc...    
        levelIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file="playerInfoIcon.png")
        fireballIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file="fireball.png")
        earthquackeIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file="earthquacke.png")
        strokeIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file="stroke.png")
        healIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file="heal.png")
        startIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file="start.png")

        self.levelIcon = levelIcon
        self.fireballIcon = fireballIcon
        self.earthquackeIcon = earthquackeIcon
        self.strokeIcon = strokeIcon
        self.healIcon = healIcon
        self.startIcon = startIcon

        #Frames to create fancy borders and titles
        mainWindowFrame = tk.Frame(master, width=780, height=380, bg="black")
        mainWindowFrame.place(x=10, y=10)

        attackButtonsFrame = tk.LabelFrame(mainWindowFrame, width=420, height=165, bg="black", relief="ridge", bd=3)
        attackButtonsFrame.place(x=300, y=210)

        playerInfoFrame = tk.LabelFrame(mainWindowFrame, width=240, height=365, bg="black", bd=3)
        playerInfoFrame.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.mainWindowFrame = mainWindowFrame

        #Canvas and stuff related to player's info
        playerInfo = tk.Canvas(playerInfoFrame, bg="black", width=225, height=340, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        playerInfo.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.playerInfo = playerInfo

        #Coordinates for .create_figure/image 
        dynamicHealthBarCoord = [14, 16, 214, 16, 195, 34, 14, 34]
        dynamicManaBarCoord = [13, 16+30, 214-100, 16+30, 195-100, 34+30, 13, 34+30]

        self.dynamicHealthBarCoord, self.dynamicManaBarCoord = dynamicHealthBarCoord, dynamicManaBarCoord


        healthBarForground = playerInfo.create_polygon(14, 15, 214, 16, 196, 34, 14, 34, fill="black", outline="black", width=2)
        dynamicHealthBar = playerInfo.create_polygon(dynamicHealthBarCoord, fill="red", width=1)
        healthBarBackground = playerInfo.create_polygon(11, 13, 220, 13, 196, 37, 11, 37, fill="", outline="gray", width=2)

        manaBarForground = playerInfo.create_polygon(14, 15+30, 214-100, 16+30, 196-100, 34+30, 14, 34+30, fill="black", outline="black", width=2)
        dynamicManaBar = playerInfo.create_polygon(dynamicManaBarCoord, fill="blue", width=1)
        manaBarBackground = playerInfo.create_polygon(11, 13+30, 220-99, 13+30, 196-99, 37+30, 11, 37+30, fill="", outline="gray", width=2)

        self.dynamicHealthBar, self.dynamicManaBar = dynamicHealthBar, dynamicManaBar

        #Buttons
        Attack_Stroke = tk.Button(mainWindowFrame, image=self.strokeIcon, command=lambda: self.Stroke(dynamicHealthBarCoord), cursor="hand1", state="disabled")
        Attack_Stroke.place(x=346.67-10, y=242-15)

        Spell_Heal = tk.Button(mainWindowFrame, image=self.healIcon, command=lambda: self.Heal(dynamicHealthBarCoord), cursor="hand1", state="disabled")
        Spell_Heal.place(x=533.33+10, y=242-15)

        Attack_Fireball = tk.Button(mainWindowFrame, image=self.fireballIcon, command=lambda: self.FireBall(dynamicHealthBarCoord, dynamicManaBarCoord), cursor="hand1", state="disabled")
        Attack_Fireball.place(x=346.67-10, y=242+60)

        Attack_Earthquake = tk.Button(mainWindowFrame, image=self.earthquackeIcon, command=lambda: self.EarthQuacke(dynamicHealthBarCoord, dynamicManaBarCoord), cursor="hand1", state="disabled")
        Attack_Earthquake.place(x=533.33+10, y=242+60)

        Enter_The_Dunjon = tk.Button(self.master, image=self.startIcon, command=self.Dunjon, cursor="hand1")
        Enter_The_Dunjon.place(x=440, y=67)

        self.Enter_The_Dunjon = Enter_The_Dunjon

        self.Attack_Stroke, self.Spell_Heal, self.Attack_Fireball, self.Attack_Earthquake =Attack_Stroke, Spell_Heal, Attack_Fireball, Attack_Earthquake

        manaRegenerationThread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.manaRegeneration(self.dynamicManaBarCoord))
        manaRegenerationThread.setDaemon(True)
        manaRegenerationThread.start()

        deathEventHandlerThread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.deathEventHandler(self.dynamicHealthBarCoord))
        deathEventHandlerThread.setDaemon(True)
        deathEventHandlerThread.start()

        #m = threading.Thread(target=lambda: manaRegeneration(dynamicManaBarCoord))
        #m.start()

    def Stroke(self, healthCoordList) :
        healthCoordList[2], healthCoordList[4] = healthCoordList[2] - 20, healthCoordList[4] - 20
        self.ennemyInfo.coords(self.ennemyDynamicHealthBar, healthCoordList)

    def Heal(self, healthCoordList) :
        healthCoordList[2], healthCoordList[4] = 214, 195
        self.playerInfo.coords(self.dynamicHealthBar, healthCoordList)

    def FireBall(self, healthCoordList, manaCoordList) :
        healthCoordList[2], healthCoordList[4] = healthCoordList[2] - 20, healthCoordList[4] - 20
        self.ennemyInfo.coords(self.ennemyDynamicHealthBar, healthCoordList)

        manaCoordList[2], manaCoordList[4] = manaCoordList[2] - 5, manaCoordList[4] - 5
        self.playerInfo.coords(self.dynamicManaBar, manaCoordList)
        self.master.update()

        i = threading.Thread(target=self.timerFireBall)
        i.setDaemon(True)
        i.start()

    def EarthQuacke(self, healthCoordList, manaCoordList) :
        healthCoordList[2], healthCoordList[4] = healthCoordList[2] - 20, healthCoordList[4] - 20
        self.ennemyInfo.coords(self.ennemyDynamicHealthBar, healthCoordList)

        manaCoordList[2], manaCoordList[4] = manaCoordList[2] - 25, manaCoordList[4] - 25
        self.playerInfo.coords(self.dynamicManaBar, manaCoordList)
        self.master.update()

        i = threading.Thread(target=self.timerEarthQuacke)
        i.setDaemon(True)
        i.start()

    def timerStroke(self) :
        self.Attack_Stroke.configure(state="disabled")
        self.master.update()

        time.sleep(0)

        self.Stroke.configure(state="active")
        self.master.update()

    def timerHeal(self) :
        self.Spell_Heal.configure(state="disabled")
        self.master.update()

        time.sleep(0)

        self.Spell_Heal.configure(stae="active")
        self.master.upgrade()

    def timerFireBall(self) :
        self.Attack_Fireball.configure(state="disabled")
        self.master.update()

        time.sleep(0)

        self.Attack_Fireball.configure(state="active")
        self.master.update()

    def timerEarthQuacke(self) :
        self.Attack_Earthquake.configure(state="disabled")
        self.master.update()

        time.sleep(0)

        self.Attack_Earthquake.configure(state="active")
        self.master.update()

    def manaRegeneration(self, manaCoordList) :
        while True :
            if manaCoordList[2] < 114 :
                manaCoordList[2], manaCoordList[4] = manaCoordList[2] + 1, manaCoordList[4] + 1
                self.playerInfo.coords(self.dynamicManaBar, manaCoordList)
                self.master.update()
                time.sleep(0.90)

            elif manaCoordList[2] >= 114 :
                manaCoordList[2], manaCoordList[4] = manaCoordList[2] + 0, manaCoordList[4] + 0
                self.playerInfo.coords(self.dynamicManaBar, manaCoordList)
                self.master.update()

    def deathEventHandler(self, healthCoordList) :
        while True :
            if healthCoordList[2] < 10 :
                self.master.destroy()

    def Dunjon(self) :
        self.Enter_The_Dunjon.place_forget()

        ennemyInfoFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self.mainWindowFrame, width=420, height=165, bg="black", bd=3)
        ennemyInfoFrame.place(x=300, y=10)

        ennemyInfo = tk.Canvas(ennemyInfoFrame, bg="black", width=415, height=160, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        ennemyInfo.place(x=0, y=0)

        ennemyDynamicHealthBarCoord = [14, 16, 214, 16, 195, 34, 14, 34] 

        ennemyHealthBarForground = ennemyInfo.create_polygon(14, 15, 214, 16, 196, 34, 14, 34, fill="black", outline="black", width=2)
        ennemyDynamicHealthBar = ennemyInfo.create_polygon(ennemyDynamicHealthBarCoord, fill="red", width=1)
        ennemyHealthBarBackground = ennemyInfo.create_polygon(11, 13, 220, 13, 196, 37, 11, 37, fill="", outline="gray", width=2)

        self.ennemyInfo, self.ennemyDynamicHealthBar = ennemyInfo, ennemyDynamicHealthBar

        self.Attack_Stroke.configure(state="active")
        self.Attack_Fireball.configure(state="active")
        self.Attack_Earthquake.configure(state="active")
        self.Spell_Heal.configure(state="active")

root = tk.Tk()
InGameWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I would be really gratefull if someone finds out how to fix this bug, also don't hesitate to correct my post. Thank you very much for your help ! ^^ (Sorry for the possible english mistakes I'm a french student)

Comment: put code not link. -1

Comment: Not just full code, but a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* code that reproduces the issue. See also "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/ -- basically, if you can take out any feature and the bug still happens the same way, *do* take that feature out.

Comment: to put widget in window you can use `pack()`, `place()` or `grid()` - use only one of them. If you use `place()` then don't use `pack()`

Comment: That said, one very notable item is that `global` declarations are local to the single scope they're in. You declare something `global` in your `__init__`, but that changes only the behavior of other code in the `__init__` function.

Comment: ...in general, it's bad design to use globals at all -- make everything member variables and then the entire potential for confusion around where something is scoped is eliminated, and moreover, that way you can have more than one instance of your objects (for testing purposes or otherwise) with distinct values.

Comment: if you use class then you should use `self.` instead of `global` to have access to element in all methods in class. You can also use `self.` to resolve problem with bug in `PhotoImage`

Comment: @furas Thanks for the tip on useing `self.` to make my .png files appear on the buttons !

Comment: when you say "reset" you mean "set on full red bar" ? I see one problem with red bar (on right side) - after I press Health it doesn't update bar to full value. But after I press atack it gets full value minus 20 and draw it - and it looks like it reset bar.

Comment: @furas Yes, it's exactly as you say, the health bar on the right side gets full value minus 20 when pressing heal then pressing an attack button. This shouldn't happen and i really don't know how to fix it, I tried to take out different features, as Charles Duffy said, but the problem remains

Comment: as for me you should use `self.ennemyInfo.coords(..)` in method Heal() to update red bar on screen when you press button `Health`. When you press attack button after health then it display shorter red bar

Comment: @furas I think you missunderstood (I don't mean to be impolite in any manner), the Heal button is designed to Heal the player, on the left is the player's health bar and on the right is ennemy's health bar. Normally pressing the Heal button shouldn't affect the ennemy's health bar.

Comment: I don't know which bar is for player, and which is for emeny. I see only red and blue bar. But I think problem is still in `Heal()` - it changes value in wrong variable. It updates enemy variable but it should update player variable.

Comment: in button `Spell_Heal` you use enemy list `self.Heal(dynamicHealthBarCoord)` so it changes value for enemy and later you see this change as "reset".  Probably you should use `self.Heal(dynamicManaBarCoord)` to change player health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In button `Spell_Heal` you use enemy list `self.Heal(dynamicHealthBarCoord)` so it changes value for enemy and later you see this change as "reset".

Probably you should use `self.Heal(dynamicManaBarCoord)` to change player health.

```
Spell_Heal = tk.Button(mainWindowFrame, text='healIcon', 
       command=lambda: self.Heal(dynamicManaBarCoord), cursor="hand1", state="disabled")
```

You may have to also change `self.ennemyDynamicHealthBar` in `Heal()`. Probably it should be `self.dynamicManaBar` but I'm not sure.

```
def Heal(self, healthCoordList) :
    healthCoordList[2], healthCoordList[4] = 214, 195
    self.playerInfo.coords(self.dynamicManaBar, healthCoordList)
```

Comment: The `dynamicManaBar` is a mana bar, namely it's a way to prevent the player of abusing the good spells, every spell consumes mana so the mana bar drops lower and lower as the player use these attacks. When the mana bar drops below a certain treshold, the player will be unable to use these attacks. So the problem is related to what you said " it changes value in wrong variable" but it isn't supposed to because the variables are all different outside functions.

Comment: maybe you need different variable in `command= ...self.Heal(...)` but it can't be `dynamicHealthBarCoord` which is used to display red bar on right side.

Comment: you should use better names - with prefix `enemy_` or `player_`. And without `dyniamic` because all is dynamic in game.

Comment: I see you have `ennemyDynamicHealthBarCoord` and maybe you should use it instead of `dynamicHealthBarCoord` in attacks.

Comment: You're right, I've found out that the variables I put in the functions aren't the ones of the ennemy's health bar, thank you very much, you've opened my eyes ! ^^